# Capturing images in ionic2 and then storing them locally on phone

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am using a [Cordova Plugin Camera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera) to capture user's profile picture. I want to store this in the app.

Here is the code that captures it:

```
 Camera.getPicture({
      quality : 75,
      destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit : true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 300,
      targetHeight: 300,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    }).then(imageData => {
      this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

    }, error => {
      console.log("ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
```

Once the image is captured, I want to store it locally so that I can display it on the profile page. Any clue how I can do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/). I would also change the option

`destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,`

for

`destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI` (android) or

`destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI` (ios)

Because `DATA_URL` can be very memory intensive and cause app crashes or out of memory errors. You should use `FILE_URI` or `NATIVE_URI` if possible.

So the idea is to grab a path to the image on the device. With that, we can move that photo to a folder created for your app (which will be in permanent
storage) and then you can use that path to show the photo in the profile page. **When I used this Cordova Plugin File it was not part of Ionic Native**, so the code is a little bit ugly...

```
Camera.getPicture(/*...theOptions*/).then(
 (imagePath) => {
     // Create a new file name by using the username or something like that
     let aDate = new Date(),
     aTime = aDate.getTime(),
     userName = this.myCustomUserService.getUserName(),
     newFileName = userName + aTime + ".jpg";

     // Returns a reference to the actual file located at imagePath
     window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imagePath,
     (file) => {

         // Returns a reference to the file system
         window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
         (fileSys) => {

             // Gets a reference to your app directory, and if it doesn't exist it creates it
             fileSys.root.getDirectory('yourAppFolderName', {create: true, exclusive: false},
             (directory) => {

                 // Moves the file to that directory, with its new name
                 file.moveTo(directory, newFileName,
                 // The file was succesfully moved and it returns a reference to it. We can use nativeURL to grab the
                 // path to the image on the device
                 (fileEntry) => {
                     this.myCustomUserService.SetProfilePhotoUrl(fileEntry.nativeURL);
                 },

                 // Now we start handing all the errors that could happen
                 (error) => {
                     // The file was unable to be moved
                     // Show error to the user
                     // ...
                 });
             },

             (error) => {
                 // Could not get a reference to your app folder
                 // Show error to the user
                 // ...
             });
         },

         (error) => {
             // Could not get a reference to the file system
             // Show error to the user
             // ...
         });
     });
 },

 (err) => {
      // Could not take picture
      // Show error to the user
      // ...
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use those options:

```
Camera.getPicture({
    sourceType: 1, // camera
    destinationType: 1, // file uri
    correctOrientation: true,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
    encodingType: 0, // jpeg
}).then((imageUri) => {
});
```

Image captured will be automatically saved. Then use `imageUri` to display image. If you want to read file content, see http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/file/

Comment: it's saved to photoAlbum. imagUri contains path to the image which I can use to display the image in the profile tab. There is a possibility that the user may delete this image from the album, is there any other private space where this image can be stored ?

Comment: Then you can use File plugin. But I think the best way is to store in database. More secure, easy to query. I suggest PouchDB plugin because it support Firefox's IndexedDB, see http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-pouchdb-sqlite-for-local-storage-in-ionic-2/